# How to calculate checksums from serial data

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, byte, checksum

I have an application written in vb.net which listen to a serial port, the following is the bytes I received:

```
B3 01 33 00 00 00 01  
B0 01 33 00 00 00 02
B1 01 33 00 00 00 03 
B6 01 33 00 00 00 04
B7 01 33 00 00 00 05
81 01 33 00 00 01 32
B0 01 33 00 00 02 00
82 01 33 00 00 02 32
B1 01 33 00 00 03 00
83 01 33 00 00 03 32
B6 01 33 00 00 04 00
84 01 33 00 00 04 32
B7 01 33 00 00 05 00
```

I want to get the correct calculation or process. How to get the first byte?

Which is `B3`, `B0`, `B1` and so on.

Comment: Do you just want to get the first byte of every seven bytes? Why not use a `% 7 == 0` check?

Comment: i want to know the process on how to get B3 if 01 33 00 00 00 01, B0 if 01 33 00 00 00 02.. sorry for my english

Comment: Use a lookup table? Or is there some algorithm that goes from the last six bytes to the first byte that I'm not aware of?

Comment: tried all the ways I know, add the last six bytes and find the checksum, get the intervals, but no luck.

Comment: @Patashu I think what the OP is saying is that he is trying to reverse-engineer the algorithm that generates the checksum B3 etc from the other 6 bytes in each row.

Comment: @peterG, that is exactly what i want to say

Comment: Anybody encountered this?